# Convert the concatenated string to timestamp in Impala

Tags: date, timestamp, unix-timestamp, impala

I have a column which is concatenation of two columns i.e, date and timestamp (both are STRING type).

Now I want to convert this new column to timestamp in **IMPALA**

```
|    New_col    |
|---------------| 
|20190616 074113|
|20190627 072350|
-----------------
```

tried all possible syntaxes like to_timestamp, unix_timestamp but everything is resulting as NULL.

Please suggest a solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
select to_timestamp('20190616 074113','yyyyMMdd HHmmss')
```

OR

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20190616 074113','yyyyMMdd HHmmss'))
```

Pls note the date time format should be correct for both functions.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @koushil roy thank you for the help, the solution which you have given is working when I give like a value, but when I use column name then it gives me NULL, i.e                                                                             select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Start_date','yyyyMMdd HHmmss'))

Comment: You are passing start_date as string. Use `select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(Start_date,'yyyyMMdd HHmmss'))`